# Inline-block elements get bumped when scrollbars appear

Tags: css

I have an option box filled with options, like this:

```
<div class="OptionBox">
  <div class="Option">
    <div class="AddRemoveIcon"></div>
    <img src="images/users/user_1000000002.jpg">
    <span class="Label">Student Name<span class="SubLabel">Student</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Option">...</div>
</div>
```

Styles are like this:

```
.OptionBox{
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width:300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Option {
  display: block;
}

.Option .AddRemoveIcon,
.Option img,
.Option .Label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I'm using inline-blocks because I like the vertical-align:middle, and the SubLabel span is not always present... But this problem occurs for float:left also...

My problem is when I have enough Options in the Option box to cause overflow-y. For whatever reason, the browsers size things correctly (ie, figure the width of each option and adjust the option box width accordingly), then add scrollbars. The result is that the widest options have their Label div bumped down a line because the scrollbars have removed X pixels from the Option box's width. When I switch to float:left for the children of an Option, the Label div wraps based on the scrollbars. In either case, the .OptionBox is never pushed to an optimum width for the widest option. The wrapping should only happen when the max-width is reached, right? [Here's a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/TQDKq/1/).

What I'm after - and I'm sure I'm asking for the moon - is either a way to reposition scrollbars so they don't take away from the width of the OptionBox, or some magic CSS rule, which tells the browser to consider the scrollbars when sizing (kind of like how box-sizing:border-box tells the browser to consider padding/borders when setting the width of an element).

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this by setting your outer-most div to be overflow: hidden. That way you won't get the y-overflow and the scrollbar will not appear. 
I'm pretty sure I saw some css to keep the scrollbar from coming up without this, but can't find it atm.